# How to use Powershell to modify SQL login permission?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0

I already used Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login in Powershell to create SQL-login with no problem.

Just for the new SQL-login created, how could I use Powershell to set its permissions as image show below? (I want to set "View any database" to be "Deny").

Thanks heaps!

[image]

Comment: How about using TSQL? You'd find a lot more help for using `GRANT` and `DENY` statements instead of messing around with management objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Valid serverpermissions:
#AdministerBulkOperations AlterAnyConnection AlterAnyCredential AlterAnyDatabase AlterAnyEndpoint AlterAnyEventNotification
#AlterAnyLinkedServer AlterAnyLogin AlterAnyServerAudit   AlterResources AlterServerState AlterSettings AlterTrace AuthenticateServer
#ConnectSql ControlServer CreateAnyDatabase CreateDdlEventNotification CreateEndpoint CreateTraceEventNotification ExternalAccessAssembly
#UnsafeAssembly ViewAnyDatabase ViewAnyDefinition ViewServerState 

    #Set variables
    $ServerInstance = ""
    $name = ""
    $action = ""

    $server = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $ServerInstance

        $perm = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ServerPermissionSet')
        $perm.$($permission.ToString()) = $true

        switch ($action)
        { 
            'Grant'  { $server.Grant($perm,$name) }
            'Deny'   { $server.Deny($perm,$name) }
            'Revoke' { $server.Revoke($perm,$name) }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks a lot. It works. BTW, where could I find the document about these library?

Comment: The code about is based on the sqlpsx CodePlex project in Module\SqlServer\SqlServer.psm1. For in on SMO classes MSDN lists properties and methods, but can be tricky to find--for example how do you know server perms are server and not login method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the SQL PowerShell module is loaded, I use this:

```
$Instance=Get-Item -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$env:COMPUTERNAME\<instance name>"
$DBPermSet=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ServerPermissionSet]::new()
$DBPermSet.Add([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ServerPermission]::ViewAnyDatabase)
$Instance.Deny($DBPermSet,"<user name>")
```